Comparison of different regularties on manifolds
I'm looking for a reference/overview which compares the theories of manifolds with different regularities, in particular continuous (topological), $k$-times differentiable, smooth, real and complex analytic ones. In particular, it should answer the following:
What are the biggest caveats when studying these different regularities coming from the smooth case? What are some intuitions which are simply wrong in general?
I am mostly familiar with smooth ones, but in general it seems one can define a regular manifold via a regular atlas: i.e. a (maximal) family of charts covering the manifold such that any local coordinate transformation is regular.
However, there seem to be some subtleties. For example:

For the tangent space of analytic manifolds you need to look at derivations of germs of smooth(?) functions, otherwise the derivation might not be localized, since there are no real analytic bump functions. Is there a general definition for the tangent space that works for all these classes?
Whitney's embedding theorem seems to be false for complex manifolds, from what I've read on wikipedia. Is this the only exception?
I can also image that topological manifolds can be pretty wild, since continuous functions can get pretty wild (but I could be wrong!).
Sard's Theorem might fail, see here for a counterexample when the map is not sufficiently differentiable.


A lesser known detail is that Sard's theorem requires a condition on the regularity of the function, namely: let $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ be a $C^k$ function such that $k\ge \max{n-m+1,1}$; then, its regular values have complement of measure $0$. This translates to the same caveat on $C^k$-differentiable functions between $C^k$ manifolds.

Great! I'll add this to the question.

You might enjoy this lecture, especially the overview she gives in the first 10 minutes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXwALAkPubc

This is way too unfocused. As a rule, you are supposed to ask one question per post. For instance, (1) is a separate question which was asked several times in different forms on this site. I have no idea what (3) is supposed to mean. You are essentially asking somebody to write a  survey paper on different notions of manifolds and how they relate to each other.

The four examples are mostly meant as motivation for the actual question down below, but I see your point. I'm mostly hoping for a good reference. This feels like something relatively standard, but I haven't found anything yet and I have already been looking for a couple of weeks.

I have edited the question to make the request more clear. Thanks again for the feedback.

First of all, a reference of the kind you are looking for simply does not exist since it would have to cover too much ground. The closest thing to such a reference that I am aware of is Chapter 1 in
Sundararaman, D., Moduli, deformations and classifications of compact complex manifolds, Research Notes in Mathematics, 45. Boston - London - Melbourne: Pitman Advanced Publishing Program. VIII, 261 p.  (1980). ZBL0435.32015.
It covers basic definitions and advances (from 1950s-1970s) in classification of topological/PL/differential manifolds as well as complex manifolds.
However, when attempting to read it, be aware of the following (taken from Nigel Hitchin's review of the book):

On the other hand, I have read it (to some extent) on my own as a graduate student and learned a lot from it. But I was probably atypical in this regard.
Another reference, discussing the relation of smooth manifolds (of different degree of smoothness) and of these to PL manifolds (i.e. existence of a PL structure) is
Munkres, J. R., Elementary differential topology. Lectures given at Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Fall, 1961. Revised ed, Annals of Mathematics Studies. 54. Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press. XI, 112 p. (1966). ZBL0161.20201.
Lastly, I would not recommend you reading the book by Kirby and Siebenmann (you surely do not have enough background for this).

I like the anti-recommendation for Kirby and Siebenmann. I was one of Kirby's students, and I never made it past the first few pages of that book, alas.

@JohnHughes: I talked to Kirby about this. He was planning to write a "follow up" to their book, where the material would be explained in an organized form. But, alas, I do not think this will ever happen. This said, I managed to use this book on few occasions as a reference for some results: When I knew what I was looking for, I would eventually find it there.
